# impact analysis and a unit root

Tags: unit-root, intervention-analysis

In conducting an impact analysis, how can we deal with a target variable, if it contains a unit root? In this case, an impact is expected to change the level of the variable. But then the impact persists and then a new impact is added due  to continuing intervention? does this mean that the impact accumulates, e.g., doubled, tripled, quadrupled, etc?